# Sorting POST data to update MySQL table rows via id in the POST name

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a form application in PHP and now I'm trying to implement updating the fields. I have made it so the POST contains data like this:

```
Array (
    '17-label' => "select label 0 ",
    '17-placeholder' => "select placeholder 0 ",
    '17-answer' => Array ( 
        "Answer 1",
        "Answer 2",
        "Answer 3"
    ),
    '18-label' => "textfield label 1",
    '18-placeholder' => "textfield placeholder 1",
    '19-label' => "textfield label 2",
    '19-placeholder' => "textfield placeholder 2"
)
```

Now as you can see I use the id of the row I want to update as the start, and then a - to identify the break and the actual column name I want to update in the column.

But how do I do this?

I know how to update, it is just, how to make sure everything goes to the right column. The first number is the id, and after the - sign it is the actual column name. But how do I do this?

Comment: the break them down into pieces and start making your insertions / updates, for the code, there's already a lot of update statement answers here on SO

Comment: Did you take a look at the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) about updating a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I have understood but if it is breaking apart and working with the constituent pieces of the array keys then perhaps this might be of use

```
foreach( $arr as $key => $str ){
    list( $id,$dash,$param )=explode( '-', $key );
    /* How do you wish to handle sub-arrays? */
    if( is_array( $param ) && !empty( $param ) )$param=implode(',',$param);

    /* do stuff with ID and PARAM */
}
```

or, probably more like:

```
foreach( $arr as $key => $value ){

    list( $id, $dash, $param )=explode( '-', $key );
    if( is_array( $value ) && !empty( $value ) )$value=implode(',',$value);

    /* do stuff with ID and PARAM and value */
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was searching!

Answer (score 0):

While writing the sql, put NULL for the column 'id'. It will automatically generate 'id', assuming it is auto-incremented.